# Python wrapper for pppack?

Tags: python, wrapper, bspline

I have searched the web extensively to find a wrapper of the [**pppack**](http://www.netlib.org/pppack/), especially the routines **bsplvb.f** and **bsplvd.f**, which return the basis of the b-splines and their derivatives. The only remotely related thing I could find is this [SE_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384859/coefficients-of-spline-interpolation-in-scipy/13400391#13400391).

So the question is: is there any wrapper available for pppack in Python?

I know about [scipy.signal.bspline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.bspline.html?highlight=bspline%20basis) and scipy.iterpolate. Both don't have what I'm looking for, at least not that I am aware of. I am basically looking for code that generates the b-spline basis functions for a given set of knots and lets me evaluate them.